# Is it possible to make this view's query more compact?

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT ma.ManningID
      ...
      ,'P01' AS Pline
      ...
FROM Manning AS ma
UNION ALL
SELECT ma.ManningID
      ...
      ,'P02' AS Pline
      ...
FROM Manning AS ma
UNION ALL
SELECT ma.ManningID
      ...
      ,'P03' AS Pline
      ...
FROM Manning AS ma
```

in case of many P... is it possible to make this view's query more compact?

Comment: Does it matter how it's formatted? As long as it's readable then that's all you should really care about. You could make each section into it's own view and then union these together but there's no advantage of doing that.

Comment: Are there really no differences between the queries other than the `Pline` column being selected? If so, why not just have a `CROSS JOIN` between `Manning` and a table populated with `Pline` values?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [table value constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd776382.aspx) (usually used in INSERT) and then CROSS JOIN on it.

```
SELECT ma.ManningID
 , ... 
 , p.Pline 
 , ...  
FROM Manning ma  
CROSS JOIN (VALUES  ('P01'),('P02'),('P03')) P(Pline)
```

Answer (score 1):

This?

```
SELECT ma.ManningID
      ...
      ,Pline
      ...
FROM Manning AS ma
cross join (select 'p01' AS Pline
union 'p02'
union 'p03') c
```